# MySQL query with duplicates and exclusion of other duplicates

Tags: mysql

the title might be confusing but I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do.
I have a MySQL table where the fields I need are:

- poster_ip
- poster_id

Now, I'm writing a query which gives me back every results in that table which has a "poster_ip" duplicates count equal or greater than 2 (it shows me if there are more results using the same "poster_ip").
This is easy:

```
SELECT * 
FROM NAME_OF_TABLE
INNER JOIN (
SELECT poster_ip
FROM NAME_OF_TABLE
GROUP BY poster_ip
HAVING COUNT( poster_ip ) >1
)dup ON NAME_OF_TABLE.poster_ip = dup.poster_ip
```

I don't care much if it's not optimized or it gives a huge load on the DB server, I don't have that problem. It works fine. Also, I need the "SELECT *" because I need to see the whole row.

Now here's the tricky part (at least for me):
I need that query returning me ONLY the duplicates of "poster_ip" where the same "poster_ip" is used by different "poster_id". That is, I need to check whether different "poster_id" are using the same "poster_ip".
I think such thing is possible, but I can't get my head on it. Could you help me please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM NAME_OF_TABLE t1
INNER JOIN NAME_OF_TABLE t2
  ON t1.poster_ip = t2.poster_ip
  AND t1.poster_id <> t2.poster_id
```

Comment: Ok, to be fair the query

SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
FROM cmc_posts t1
INNER JOIN cmc_posts t2
  ON t1.poster_ip = t2.poster_ip
  AND t1.poster_id <> t2.poster_id

was more useful for me. Actually, it's almost perfect. Is there a way to eliminate the duplicates which are using both the same "poster_ip" AND "poster_id"? I've tried a couple of things but none has worked so far.

Comment: Reverted :) - Not quite sure what you mean by 'both the same "poster_ip" AND "poster_id"' though. Are you talking about `SELECT DISTINCT t1.poster_id, t1.poster_ip`?

Comment: What I mean is: that query retrieves me three rows with the same exact "poster_ip" AND "poster_id". I don't care seeing those three rows, what do I care is seeing only one combination of the same "poster_ip" and "poster_id". Since we're talking about a DB with 500.000 records and more than 11.000 duplicates, it is quite important for me to eliminate such duplicates. Is it more clear now?